# sum a Google sheets column up to current row in arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, sum, cumulative-sum, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to sum a Google sheets column up to the current row. Everything within the sum formula seems to work okay when I just use copy and paste, but it does not seem to work the same in an arrayformula. Why? What formula can I use to make it work? I'm running the function on column g, trying to return the latest sum on the adjacent column i. Here's the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DLf3ONimFsymQE3rJ_18rhAfSoYQ3homh3lDEXeJFhI/edit#gid=0

And here's the formula:

```
=arrayformula(if(F2:F<>"", sum(indirect("r1c7", false):indirect("r[0]c7",false)),""))
```

Instead of returning the sum up to the latest row, it is returning only the number from the first row (row 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
=BYROW(F2:F,LAMBDA(each,IF(each<>"",SUM(F1:each),"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

try running total with lambda scan:

```
=SCAN(, G2:INDEX(G:G, MAX(ROW(G:G)*(G:G<>""))), LAMBDA(a, b, a+b))
```

[image]